# Cannot link with fmt.h on macOS after installing with brew

Tags: c++, cmake

I have install all required packages listed in cmakelists. However, for package fmt, it still told me can not find the fmt.h.

```
[  5%] Building CXX object libe-base/CMakeFiles/e-base.dir/src/base/exception.cc.o

In file included from /Users/yanghurui/Desktop/libraries/libe-base/src/base/exception.cc:1:
In file included from /Users/yanghurui/Desktop/libraries/libe-base/include/e/base/exception.hh:4:
/Users/yanghurui/Desktop/libraries/libe-    base/include/e/base/object.hh:9:10: fatal error: 'fmt/format.h' file     not found
#include <fmt/format.h>
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
make[2]: *** [libe-base/CMakeFiles/e-    base.dir/src/base/exception.cc.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [libe-base/CMakeFiles/e-base.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I have installed the fmt pack using brew and try to add path

```
export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"
```

Just wonder if the problem goes with brew or mac? because this project compile normally on Linux like fedora and ubuntu.

Thanks~

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question

Answer (score 0):

Setting `PATH` has no effect. Brew installed your fmt package into the `/opt/homebrew/include` directory.

Add the following to your CMakeLists.txt:

```
target_include_directories(e-base PUBLIC /opt/homebrew/include)
```